# Bumblebee with AMD Radeon 530 (Laptop with Debian)

Tags: debian, laptop, amd-graphics, bumblebee

I'm about to change my old laptop; I'm interested in a Dell Laptop with new i5 (8000 series) with dedicated graphic card AMD Radeon® 530.

I used to have bumblebee installed on my old-one in order to be able to switch between integrated and dedicated card but the dGPU was nVidia (with bumblebee-nvidia deb package present in debian repos): is bumblebee working with AMD dedicated graphics card or is it limited with nVidia?
If so, has someone tried it with this hardware on Debian?

Eventually I need to get working both video cards then I would appreciate different answers rather than deactivating the integrated card using the BIOS to install AMD driver only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bumblebee has no support for AMD video cards at the moment (it explicitly searches for Intel+Nvidia or Nvidia+Nvidia combinations). In theory support for it could be added (there is an open issue [here](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/52)), but I don't think it will happen any time soon.

To get both cards working, I suggest looking into https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME, this is what I use nowadays in order to make use of external monitors (which are connected to my Nvidia dGPU). Some distributions use this technology automatically behind the scenes (I think Fedora with GNOME and maybe Ubuntu?).